# Intentional RF emitter failing unintentional emission test?

Tags: rf, emc, fcc

Suppose a commercial product uses a FCC pre-certified WiFi module. If the quality is not consistent throughout the batch, I'd guess some pre-certified modules may produce unacceptable emissions. In that case, could these emissions fail the unintentional emission test for the final product? Or is it that pre-certified modules are somehow isolated during the test such that the emissions produced by the pre-certified modules will not affect the unintentional emission test outcomes?

Comment: There are a lot of "Ifs", "guesses" and "coulds" in your question - individual modules may well be certified **but** by creating a new product you also create new opportunities for unwanted emissions (e.g. power lines/tracks acting as aerials). The only way to **know** is to test the final product.

Answer (score 0):

Well possible that an unit that has approved building blocks fails as one new system. The cumulated total emission can be too much due a simple summing or due increased individual emissions caused by new interactions. Do not rely only on "all my parts already have the certificate".

Do not believe? What interactions????

Think about a radio device and a too high voltage power supply for it. The higher voltage can easily raise the spurious outputs too high or the output at the legitimate frequency can have too high power.